# $\int_{C} 2\text{Re}(z) f(z)/z dz$ on unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to calculate $\int_{C} 2\text{Re}(z) f(z)/z dz$ on unit circle $C : \{z: \lvert z \rvert = 1\}$, where $f$ is analytic on $\lvert z \rvert < 2$

My attempt:
Since $2\text{Re}(z) = z + \bar{z}$, we get $\int_{C}f(z) + \frac{\bar{z}}{z}f(z) dz = \int_{C} f(z) + f(z)/z^{2} dz$. Here, second equation follows as $z\bar{z} = 1$ on unit circle. first term is $0$ by Cauchy's theorem, Second term is $2\pi if'(0)$ by Cauchy's integral formula. Am I right?

I'm not sure since this problem is introduced before Cauchy's integral formula. So Is there any way to calculate it without Cauchy's integral formula?

Comment: What do we know about $f$?

Comment: $f$ is analytic on $\lvert z \rvert < 2$

Comment: Minor point: the second term is $2\pi\mathrm{i} f'(0)$.

Comment: Thanks! I edit it.